# This bash script is not working - Linux/Python

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

**I can't seem to figure out how to get his bash script working.**

```
#!/bin/bash 
export WORKON_HOME=~/.envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon staging_env
```

It **is using viretualenv and virualenvwrapper in order to use a Python virtual environment.**

Typing these commands in the shell work perfectly fine, running it as a bash script does not work though.

---

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a script, it creates its own instance of the shell (bash, in this case). Because of this, the changes are lost when the script ends and the script's shell is closed.

To make the changes stick, you'll have to `source` the script instead of running it.